# ¿Cómo resolver posibles ambigüedades en llamadas a funciones? (Clase Abstracta)

Tags: javascript, funciones, clase-abstracta

¿Cómo llamo a la función de nombre "metodo()" perteneciente a la clase A y no a la de la B?

```js
    class A
    {
     constructor() 
     {
        }
    
        metodo()
        {
          this.virtual();
        }
    
        virtual()
        {
          console.log("Original"); 
        }
    }
     
    class B extends A
    {
     constructor()
     {
        super();
        }

        metodo()
        {
        }
    
        virtual()
        {
          console.log("Sustituto"); 
        }
    }
    
    b = new B();    
    b.metodo();
```

La salida obtenida deseada debería ser esta:

```
Sustituto
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es obtener Sutituto en la salida, sencillamente elimina el método `metodo` y la función del padre se encargará de llamar al `virtual` de la clase B.

Además, te falta la llamada `super()` en el constructor de la clase B.

```js
class A
{
    constructor() 
    {
    }

    metodo()
    {
      this.virtual();
    }

    virtual()
    {
      console.log("Original"); 
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    constructor() 
    {
      super();
    }

    virtual()
    {
      console.log("Sustituto"); 
    }
}

b = new B();    
b.metodo();
```

Comment: el constructor tambien se puede herdar, si se quita no pasara nada

Comment: @IvanIsayenko poder se puede, pero no lo recomiendo por homogeneidad del código

Comment: Gracias a los dos por vuestras explicaciones!! Aunque ahora tengo otro dilema porque daría como validas las dos repuestas que me habies dado y solo me dejan aceptar una. :-( creo que voy a hacer lo mismo que Pilatos... Voy  a esperar hasta mañana y quien tenga un mayor número de votos positivos esa será la que de por valida. Pero que conste que si fuera por mi las aceptaría a las dos. Gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: @IvánRodríguez es un problema conocido en el sitio. Puedes basarte tambien en la fecha de publicación , la explicacion más clara o el usuario con menos rep hahah

Comment: Creo que lo voy a dejar a decisión popular. El que tenga mas votos positivos,

Answer (score 3):

Te explico un par de conceptos.  Aunque JS no es fuerte en programación orientado a objetos, te da la posibilidad de declarar y/o usar clases. Creaste dos clases, A y B, la ultima extiende de A. Cuando una clase extiende de otra, hereda automaticamente todo, en este caso hereda todos los metodos. Cuando tu declaras el metodo `metodo()` en clase B, lo que haces es **sobreescribirla**, entonces ya no es la misma que en clase A. El codigo arreglado quedaria de esta manera:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {}
    metodo() {
        this.virtual();
    }
    virtual() {
        console.log("Original");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    virtual() {
        console.log("Sustituto");
    }
}

b = new B();
b.metodo();
```

Aunque en la clase B no exista el metodo `metodo()`, este se podra llamar ya que es herdado.
Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Sense cap problema!